# Activator/Play commands make Cygwin bash commands invisible

Tags: bash, playframework, cygwin, typesafe-activator, mintty

I'm using Cygwin and any time I use an Activator command (e.g., `activator run` or `activator "eclipse with-source=true"`), any text thereafter is invisible.  It's being typed, because if I hit enter, the command will be executed, but I cannot see it.

I've done some searching of this issue, and I'm not the only one to experience it, as I've learned I can blindly type `stty sane` and I'll get my text visible again, but that's a bit onerous.

Other tips suggest commenting out a certain line in `<activator>\minimal\activator`, but looking through that file, I see many lines for detecting if the terminal being used is Cygwin and then specific handling for that, so I'm not sure what to edit nor why it isn't already handling the fact that I'm using Cygwin.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A couple of possible answers: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/6sm3rm8359Q  ;  http://www.dont-panic.cc/capi/2014/06/17/cygwin-play-framework-typesafe-activator/comment-page-1/

Comment: yea, those are the sites i had seen when i googled this issue, but thank you for helping out.  like i said, i'm currently just typing `stty sane`, but i'd rather find a way to more efficiently/effectively fix this issue.  the activator startup script looks like it's handling cygwin specifically fro this issue, which is one fo the reasons i'm confused to be having it; i'm not sure what to change if it looks like it's handling what these posts are pointing out is the issue.

Comment: The little script mentioned in the second link above should do the trick. Then just call it instead of activator. #!/bin/bash
activator $@
R=$?
stty sane
exit $R